# CLI dll compiled for release, depends on debug versions of vc Runtime dlls

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, clr

I'm building a C# WPF app (.NET 7.0) that uses a CLI/CLR .dll. Both the app and dll are built in release mode, as is the static library the dll wraps. Despite all this, the dll still depends on debug versions of VC runtime dlls (eg. msvcp140d.dll, vcruntime140d.dll etc.)

Obviously it's not a huge issue to include said dlls with my project, but also obviously, this shouldn't be necessary.

I'd appreciate if anyone has any ideas what could cause this

Comment: "as is the static library", I would look there first.  Use the linker's /VERBOSE option to get insight.

Comment: Turns out that despite the CLI/CLR project being set to release mode, it was still being set to include debug symbols for whatever reason.